# ColdFusion Database settings

Tags: mysql, database, configuration, coldfusion

Where is a place to look for db settings in ColdFusion? I would like to connect to the db via sequel pro.

Comment: By the way, it's "ColdFusion".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a DSN set up on the server that the CF is using?  That can be used to connect to the database, and would specify the name, password, database and a bit more.  That's accessed through the CFAdministrator page, not in the CF code itself.  Only the DSN name is used in the code.

Edit: In the CF admin page, go to the Data & Services tab, then choose Data Sources.  That is where the list of DSNs exist.  Select a data source to see the connection information.  The password is masked.

Comment: There is not much in the admin I can see to go off of.  I am not too familiar with CF but do not see anything in the admin panel.  Is there no where I can find parameters to connect to the db from having ftp access?

Comment: I added information on where the DSN information is found.  It's possible that your database information is not set there, that it is in the code, but the DSN is the better choice, since it allows you to move from dev to test to prod without changing your code.

Comment: I do not have CF Admin access but that answered my question correctly.  Thank you!